# Unable to connect via https: using below Ngnix configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Is this configuration correct? I am able to access via http but not via https

I have a nginx installed on Ubuntu 20 on GCP compute engine. Below is nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testprojects.com www.testprojects.com;
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen default_server 443 ssl;

    server_name testprojects.com www.testprojects.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/testprojects_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/testprojects_com.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.index.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.index.error.log;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location = /test {
            return test.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your redirecting `http` to `https`

You have to `http` to `https`

Which is mean, when any request comes with `http`, just redirect to `https`

Change this line:

```
return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
```